# Laravel 6.2 whereHasMorph not returning expected value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6.2

Need some help for laravel polymorphic. I'm trying to filter from the main table which is Comment to get its morph tables and search for the key word FOO. I have tried with whereHas but get error saying to use whereHasMorph so I tried changing whereHas to whereHasMorph. But every time i filter, the result will be an empty collection even if the value exist in the table. So I went through laravel documentation and found the below sample. I tried the sample but I'm still getting an empty collection. I have tried reading but could not find a fix.

Below is the sample code which I have tried

** Models **

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'comments';

    protected $fillable = [
        'body',
        'commentable_id',
        'commentable_type'
    ];

    public function commentable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'body'
    ];

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Video extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'videos';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'url'
    ];

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
}
```

** Controller **

```
public function commentList () {

    $comments = App\Comment::whereHasMorph(
        'commentable',
        ['App\Post', 'App\Video'],
        function ($query) {
            $query->where('title', 'like', '%foo%');
        }
    )->get();

    dd($comments);
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing out or do i need to configure something or install some packages ?

```
"php": "^7.2",
"laravel/framework": "^6.2",
```

Images of DB table

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you create these comments manually or with the relationship? Does something like `dd(Comment::find(1)->commentable);` work?

Comment: manually. Nope. if i find one record and call the morph then it works fine. but i filter multiple then it does not work.

Comment: Does `whereHasMorph()` work when you remove the leading backslash from `commentable_type`?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and dont know why suddenly work when i remove the first \ in the DB.

Changed \App\Post in the table to App\Post and also in the code then it work already. Thanks for all the help.